# C++: Char iteration over string (I'm getting crazy)

Tags: c++, string, iterator

I have this string:

```
std::string str = "presents";
```

And when I iterate over the characters, they come in this order:

```
spresent
```

So, the last char comes first.

This is the code:

```
uint16_t c;
printf("%s: ", str.c_str());
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.size(); i += extractUTF8_Char(str, i, &c)) {
    printf("%c", c);
}
printf("\n");
```

And this is the exctract method:

```
uint8_t extractUTF8_Char(string line, int offset, uint16_t *target) {
 uint8_t ch = uint8_t(line.at(offset));
 if ((ch & 0xC0) == 0xC0) {
  if (!target) {
   return 2;
  }
  uint8_t ch2 = uint8_t(line.at(offset + 1));
  uint16_t fullCh = (uint16_t(((ch & 0x1F) >> 2)) << 8) | ((ch & 0x3) << 0x6) | (ch2 & 0x3F);
  *target = fullCh;
  return 2;
 }
 if (target) {
 *target = ch;
 }
 return 1;
}
```

This method returns the length of the character. So: 1 byte or 2 bytes. And if the length is 2 bytes, it extracts the UNICODE point out of the UTF8 string.

Comment: Offtopic: don't pass strings by value unless you have to. I.e., i'd change the prototype of extractUTF8_Char to `uint8_t extractUTF8_Char(const string& line, ...`

Comment: Also off topic: even with @lijie's fix, this won't work correctly with non-ASCII input due to the use of `%c` (unless your compiler supports 16-bit `char`).

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, I know. But I was for testing purposes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

your first `printf` is printing nonsense (the initial value of `c`). The last `c` gotten is not printed.

This is because the call to `extractUTF8_char` is occurring in the last clause of the `for` statement. You might want to change it to

```
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < str.size();) {
    i += extractUTF8_Char(str, i, &c);
    printf("%c", c);
}
```

instead.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a visit to the psychiatrist! Thank you!